# CheckBox в ExpandableListView

Tags: expandablelistview, android, checkbox, java

Есть ExpandableListView с кастомным адаптером:
Для Child:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:background="@drawable/border_one_task"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox_task"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_task_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Задача1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="28sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_task_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="10.12.2014"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#0000ff" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_task_map"
            android:layout_width="25sp"
            android:layout_height="25sp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_mapmode" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Необходимо обрабатывать событие клика на CheckBox. При этом необходимо вызвать метод из вызывающей активити(Что бы обновить данные). Каким образом можно это сделать?

Comment: @Lucky_spirit все получилось) спасибо:)

Comment: Могу сделать это ответом, а Вы отметите, как принятый.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте Interface и объявите в нём метод. Activity заставьте имплементить этот Interface. В конструктор адаптера для этого ListView добавьте параметр Interface, который Вы создали, и при создании этого адаптера передайте this Активити, которое реализует этот интерфейс. Сохраните его, как поле класса. При нажатии на CheckBox вызывайте метод этого интерфейса, вызовется метод у Activity. Это простой пример реализации Callback.

Comment: Возможно пригодится кому-нибудь:)

http://freehabr.ru/blog/java/553.html

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант через Context. Не уверен что он правильный.

```
if (context instanceof MyActivity) {
   ((MyActivity) context).my_method();
}
```

Comment: так не получилось)

Comment: Метод в активити должен быть public. Контекст должен быть вида MyActivity.this, а не getApplicationContext(). Так должно получиться. Так сложно определить причину того, что именно не получилось, не увидев полного кода.

Comment: @otr23 Согласна. Но,к счастью, получилось первым методом)